# mandrill integration with osclass 3.3.x

Tags: php, mailchimp, mandrill, osclass

I try to setup mail server for my Osclass website.but it doesn't work [image: fields for mail server].

I try every port 25, 587 or 2525 for non encryption but it not work. Is there is any mandrill plugin available for Osclass? anyone who has already integrated mandrill and Osclass can please tell what is missing?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you're not specifying an email address in the "Mail from" field, which might be causing some issues because you do need to specify a sender email address and not just a name.  However, if you're seeing an error when you try to send, it'd be useful to provide the specific error information since that's going to provide some clues as to why you're having issues.  Since this uses SMTP, you may also want to get in touch with your hosting provider since they may not support outbound SMTP connections.  More details can be found in the [Mandrill KB here](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/24633717-Why-am-I-getting-a-Relay-Access-Denied-error-trying-to-send-through-SMTP-).

Comment: port 465 with ssl encryption with check at "SMTP authentication enabled" works fine :)