# OSCLASS: Validate an email address

Tags: osclass

I'm a newbie to OSClass. I have downloaded a setup and configured in my machine. In user registration page, there is no client validation. It is validating a form in server side. I'm using modern theme. What kind of criteria are being validated in osclass for an email address?

Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

you have set mail server in osclass setting.you can set it with mandrill free account 12000 emails/month.for more detail you check [mandrill integration with osclass 3.3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21038596/mandrill-integration-with-osclass-3-3-x)

Answer (score 0):

Modern theme is quite old now and not supported anymore.

[Bender](https://github.com/osclass/theme-bender) is the current theme for Osclass nowadays.

In Bender and other theme, front validation is usually handle by the jQuery Validate plugin but it's completely up to you.

Take a look in the *.form.php file [in the Osclass Github](https://github.com/osclass/Osclass/tree/master/oc-includes/osclass/frm). This is where Javascript is done (ugly but the subject is a work in progress).

You could also take a look at Pop theme (designed by the Osclass team), [here](http://market.osclass.org/themes/general/pop-theme_274).